# How to assign promise then response to external variable?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, promise

I am trying to reuse a code which returns an auth token to test my protected endpoints.

I tried returning the promise response inside a callback. Here is the code:

common.js

```
const authToken = accessToken => {
conn
.connect()
.then(() => {
  request(app)
    .post("/register")
    .send({ username: "newUser", password: "newPass" })
    .then(res => {
      request(app)
        .post("/login")
        .send({ username: "newUser", password: "newPass" })
        .then(res => {
          token = res.body.token;
          accessToken(token);
        })
        .catch(err => done(err));
    })
    .catch(err => done(err));
})
.catch(err => done(err));
};

module.exports = { authToken };
```

auth.test.js

```
const authToken = require("../common").authToken();

let token;
before(done => {
  authToken(token => {
   token = token;
   done();
  });
})
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: authToken is not a function
```

Comment: Where's the code where you import authToken?

Comment: Hi, I've already added the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const authToken = require("../common").authToken();
```

to this:

```
const authToken = require("../common").authToken;
```

Your original code loads the module common.js, gets the exports object from it, gets the `.authToken` property from the exports and then calls that function reference in that exports object and assigns the return value from executing that function to the `authToken` variable.  Since the function returns nothing, `authToken` will be `undefined` and certainly not a function and thus will cause an error when you try to use it like a function.

Instead, you want to import just the function reference itself and assign the function reference to your `authToken` variable.  Importing just the function reference will then allow you to call it later the way you are in `auth.test.js`.